EventBridge events not firing lambda functions on initial Autoscaling Group start
According to my cloudwatch logs, my lambda functions never fire on the initial launch of my autoscaling group. The only time I have ever seen the eventbridge send an event to my lambda function is when i increased the desired capacity from 0 to 1. Whenever my desired capacity starts at 1 I get absolutely nothing. My goal ultimately is to assign an elastic ip address to all my autoscaled instances. I'm trying to use a lambda function to accomplish this, however its proving to not be simple.
Has anyone ever had a similar problem to this?
resource "aws_autoscaling_group" "ssh_proxy_group" {
  launch_template {
    id      = xxx
    version = "$Latest"
  }

  desired_capacity    = 0
  min_size            = 0
  max_size            = 20
}

resource "aws_autoscaling_policy" "scale_out_policy" {
  name                   = "ScaleOutPolicy"
  scaling_adjustment     = 1  # Number of instances to add
  adjustment_type        = "ChangeInCapacity"
  cooldown               = 300  # Time between scaling activities (5 minutes)
  autoscaling_group_name = aws_autoscaling_group.ssh_proxy_group.name
}

resource "aws_cloudwatch_event_rule" "instance_launch_rule" {
  name        = "instance-launch-rule"
  description = "Triggers when an EC2 instance is successfully launched by the Auto Scaling group."

  event_pattern = jsonencode({
    source = ["aws.autoscaling"],
    "detail-type" = ["EC2 Instance Launch Successful"],
    detail = {
      AutoScalingGroupName = [aws_autoscaling_group.ssh_proxy_group.name]
    }
  })
}

resource "aws_lambda_permission" "allow_eventbridge" {
  statement_id  = "AllowExecutionFromEventBridge"
  action        = "lambda:InvokeFunction"
  function_name = aws_lambda_function.allocate_ip_to_ec2.function_name
  principal     = "events.amazonaws.com"
  source_arn    = aws_cloudwatch_event_rule.instance_launch_rule.arn
}

resource "aws_cloudwatch_event_target" "trigger_lambda" {
  rule = aws_cloudwatch_event_rule.instance_launch_rule.name
  arn  = aws_lambda_function.allocate_ip_to_ec2.arn

  depends_on = [aws_lambda_permission.allow_eventbridge]
}

